# DNS not working between two linked docker containers - getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN error

Tags: docker, dns, containers, postman

I am attempting to setup a temporary environment where I can execute ATs against a web application. To achieve this I have 3 docker containers:

Container 1: Database (mongo_local)

`docker build -t mongo_local ./test/AT/mongo
 docker run --name mongo_local -d -p 27017:27017 mongo_local`

Container 2 (Web application):

`docker run --name mywebapp_local -d -p 4431:4431 --link mongo_local -v /applicationdata:/applicationdata mywebapp`

Container 3 (Newman test runner):

`docker build -t newman_runner ./test/AT/newman
 docker run --name newman_runner --link mywebapp_local newman_runner`

The web application can access the database successfully using the following connection string: `mongodb://mongo_local:27017/mydb`, note that I am able to reference mongo_local, I dont have to specify an IP address for the mongo_local container.

The newman test runner runs postman tests against the web application and all tests execute successfully when I specify the IP address of the mywebapp_local container i.e. 10.0.0.4 in the URL, however if I specify the name mongo_local in the URL it does not work.

Hence `https://mywebapp_local/api/v1/method1` does not work but `https://10.0.0.4/api/v1/method1` does work.

The error Im getting is

`getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mywebapp_local mywebapp_local:443 at request ...`

I've tried using -add-host in the docker run command and this makes no difference. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As you have it set up, the `newman_runner` container doesn't `--link mongo_local` and that's why it can't see it.

Docker has been discouraging explicit inter-container links for a while.  If you create a Docker-internal network and attach each container to it

```
docker network create testnet
docker run --net testnet ...
```

it will be able to see all of the other containers on the same network by their `--name` without an explicit `--link`.

Comment: The newman_runner only needs to get access to the mywebapp_local web application, it does not need direct access to the database container. In relation to setting up a nework, we are aware that linking has been deprecated but we want to avoid setting up docker networks for now.

Comment: I tried to add another --link mongo_local but it makes not difference. The issue is to do with failing to resolve mywebapp_local for a reason that is unknown to me